# Git push to remote that requires ssh key

Tags: git, ssh, deployment

Deploys to my remote server fail with a "permission denied" error:

```
git push prod master
```

**Error**

```
deploy@<IP>: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I can ssh into the server:

```
$ ssh my_server
```

Which I have setup in ~/.ssh/config.

```
Host my_server
    HostName <IP>
    User deploy
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_server_rsa
```

I previously deployed with password authentication like this.

```
$ git remote add prod deploy@<IP>:app_prod
$ git push prod master
```

And then inputted the password when prompted.
But now that I've switched to an ssh key, my deploys fail.

So my question is, how do I get `git push` to use `~/.ssh/config`?

I can't figure out how to make this work, and don't know what to google to find an example.
Probably missing something super basic here...

Comment: Did you update the remote url, i.e. `git remote set-url prod ssh://my_server/path/to/repo.git`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A config file with `my_server` `Host` entry means it is a shortcut for:

```
ssh -i  ~/.ssh/my_server_rsa deploy@<IP>
```

So to use it, as commented, you need for the remote prod URL to use that `my_server` config entry:

```
git remote set-url prod my_server:/path/to/repo
# or
git remote set-url prod ssh://my_server/path/to/repo
```